# Splitting up a constructor for pattern matching?

Tags: haskell

If I have a function like so:

```
func:: Arg1->Arg2->String
```

and Arg1 has a constructor like:

```
data Arg1 = something1 something2 something3
```

I want to pattern match on one of the Arg1 constructors within func (below I have pattern matched on "Val1"):

```
func:: Arg1->Arg2->String
func (a b Val1) e = "Something"
```

but it keeps saying I have a problem with parsing symbol 'a'

The variables in the brackets just represent Arg1??? "e" is the Arg2 parameter.

EDIT: This seems to work:

```
func:: Arg1-> Arg2-> String
func (A b Val1) e = "Something"
```

but I cannot pattern-match on A because i'm not bothered about that value.

EDIT2: Seems like I need to do:

```
data Arg1 = Arg1 something1 something2 something3
```

for it to work?!?!

Comment: Re. your second edit. Yes, that is how you declare a new data type in Haskell. It could be `data Foo = Bar ConstituentType1 Constituent2` or, as you chose, `data Foo = Foo ...`. I suggest you read [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/) or [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pattern match on the constructor as well.
You also forgot to specify the constructor for `Arg1`.

```
func :: Arg1 -> Arg2 -> String
func (Arg1 a b Val1 d) e = "Foobar"
```

Comment: It just says data constructor Arg1 is not in scope (it recognised it for the function declaration, just not the second line)

Comment: It seems to be because I am using a variable "a" and not a recognised constructor "A" for the first argument. This is a problem because I dont care what the value is for the first argument. If I use "_" it still complains....